# Multiple SharePoint Apps or Single SharePoint Apps per "Feature"?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, best-practices

I want to know what is the **best practice** for deploying a "Solution" in **SharePoint Online.**

For example, if I want to create an "**Employee Site with Leaves"** in SharePoint Server 2013, when we did this as a **SharePoint Solution (.wsp),** we created **1 solution with multiple SharePoint Projects** inside. **Features** handle deployment of 'features' (ex. Branding is 1 feature, Columns / Content Types is 1 feature, Site Structure is 1 feature, etc.).

However, for **SharePoint Apps,** does it make sense to separate it into **multiple SharePoint Apps?** For example, given the "Employee Site with Leaves", 1 SharePoint App is for Branding, 1 SharePoint App is for Columns / Content Types, 1 SharePoint App is for Site Structure? Or can everything be in just **1 SharePoint App**?

I'm also looking at this in a **maintenance / upgrade** perspective if we need to do any upgrades. In .wsp, I can just use the **versioning** and **Upgrade** using powershell, but not sure how it is for SharePoint Apps.

Thank you!